# How to find out the validity of a URL in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I don't know of the title is completely appropriate, but here's what I actually want to do. I have urls which point to mp3 files, now some are valid and and some are not, as of now, so before I render the controls for playback of those audio files in my UI, I want to check whether the URL will give me the mp3 or result in a 404. How can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make an HTTP request and check the response code

```
final response =
  await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
```

See https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data for more details.

A `HEAD` request will be more efficient though when you only want to check if the URL is valid because it doesn't actually download content.

```
final response =
  await http.head(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

Comment: I've encountered servers where HEAD and GET both return the full content.  Just a datapoint.

Comment: For anyone else. ```import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;```